# How can I make this layout 3 imagebutton 1 progressbar?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I make this layout? Above is the image, below is a box of testo. In between is the problem, are 3 buttons and 1 progressbar.

As this image:

[image]

Comment: i dont see the problem here. This is a very easy one. Game of LinearLayouts if you are a beginner. I would suggest you figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code : you just change the Button to ImageButton and use imagebutton of your choice

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFF" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:layout_weight=".8"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Play"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                 />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Stop" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Pause" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".8"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enter Your Text"
            android:laout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Next time try it yourself....

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions, please add all reqired attributes 
(just pseudo mark-up) :

[image]

```
   <LinearLayout
    orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView/>

                <LinearLayout
                orientation="horizontal">
                     <Button/>
                     <LinearLayout
                     orientation="verical">
                         <ScrollBar/>
                         <LinearLayout
                         orientation="horizontal"
                         gravity="right">
                                  <Button/>
                                  <Button/>
                      </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView/>
    </LinearLayout>
```